# Compiling a GLUT program

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, glut

Can some one tell me what is the command to compile a simple GLUT program on the macos platform? I have a floder with main.cpp and 2 .data files.Currently I do something like

gcc -o program program.cpp -lglu -lGL -lGLU -lX11

but it returns saying library not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the difference .Actually on Mac you got to use the -framework option instead of -l and then also g++ instead of the gcc.It works now.

Answer (score 0):

typo? try linking with `-lglut` (rather than `-lglu`)